# Update feature object's state using Rally PHP

Tags: rally

I'm trying to update a feature's state using the Rally PHP. I thought this code would work :

Connection::rally()->update('state', '7177179173', array('Name' => 'In the Backlog'));

but this is giving me a "not authorized" error :

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RallyApiError' with message 'Not authorized to update: State 7177179173'

Can someone please help me with this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. Every state has a different Object ID; "In the Backlog" has an Object id of : 7177179173.

This line of code does the trick:

`Connection::rally()->update('feature', '12848970281', array('state' => '7177179173'));`

What it means: update the state of a feature (that has an Object ID of 12848970281) to "In the Backlog" (that has an Object ID of 7177179173)

Comment: That's correct. You may also develop your code further by querying on states to get the fully qualified URLs of the States so that you may use Names instead of OIDs when setting State. See a Ruby example for a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726215/rally-ruby-toolkit-how-to-get-url-of-portfolio-items-state

Answer (score 0):

This format will work:

```
"State" => "/state/12345"
```

where 12345 is the OID of the desired State