# Rally Ruby toolkit: how to get URL of Portfolio Item's state?

Tags: ruby, rally

Is there an example in Ruby using rally_api how to set State of a feature as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706280/update-feature-objects-state-using-rally-php)?

Specifically, is there a way to query the ObjectID or the fully qualified path of state to use

```
"State" => "Developing"
```

instead of

```
"State" => "/state/<ObjectID>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to query State, create a hash, and populate the hash with the query results, where State Name is the key and State _ref is the value:

```
state_results.each do |s|
    s.read
    state_hash[s["Name"]] = s["_ref"]
end
```

Then we can update a State:

```
features.each do |f|
    field_updates={"State" => state_hash["Developing"]}
    f.update(field_updates)
end
```

Here is a code example:

```
@rally = RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(config)

queryState = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
queryState.type = :state
queryState.fetch = "true"
queryState.workspace = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/11111" } 
queryState.project = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/22222" } #use valid OIDs
queryState.query_string = "(TypeDef.Name = \"Feature\")"

state_hash = Hash.new

state_results = @rally.find(queryState)

state_results.each do |s|
    s.read
    #puts "Ref: #{s["_ref"]}, Name: #{s["Name"] }, TypeDef: #{s["TypeDef"]}" 
    state_hash[s["Name"]] = s["_ref"]
end 

query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
query.type = "portfolioitem/feature"
query.fetch = "Name,FormattedID"
query.workspace = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/1111" } 
query.project = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/22222" } #use valid OIDs
query.query_string = "(Name = \"my feature\")"


results = @rally.find(query)
features = [];

results.each do |f|
     f.read
     puts "Current state of Feature #{f["FormattedID"]}: #{f["State"].to_s}"
     features << f
end


features.each do |f|
    field_updates={"State" => state_hash["Developing"]}
    f.update(field_updates)
    puts "Feature #{f["FormattedID"]} is now in State: #{f["State"].to_s}"
end
```