# What is the correct "Type" to use for querying portfolio items using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rally

I'm trying to write what I thought would be a simple query to get one particular portfolio item from our workspace.

Here is my query code:

> queryConfig = { 
>          type : 'PortfolioItem',
>          key : 'stories',
>          query: '(Name = "Maintenance_Txn_Policy_Change")',
>          fetch: 'Name,Tags'
>        };

```
 rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('__WORKSPACE_OID__', 
                                     '__PROJECT_OID__',
                                     '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__', 
                                     '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__'); 
rallyDataSource.findAll(queryConfig, showStories);
```

When I run this rallyDataSource comes back as undefined.

If I modify my code to look for userstories in stead:

> queryConfig = { 
>          type : 'hierarchicalrequirement',
>          key : 'stories',
>         query: '(Iteration.Name = "Iteration 2")',
>          fetch: 'Name,Tags'
>        };

```
 rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('__WORKSPACE_OID__', 
                                     '__PROJECT_OID__',
                                     '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__', 
                                     '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__'); 
rallyDataSource.findAll(queryConfig, showStories);
```

I get correct answers.

So my quesiton is, what do I specify as the Type: in the query to get portfolio items, in particular, Features? I've tried some examples I've seen on this site (portfoilioitem, portfolioitem/Feature, etc.) but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using deprecated [AppSDK1](https://help.rallydev.com/app-sdk-1x) that predates introduction of PortfolioItem objects in WS API. Use [AppSDK2](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/). See [this example](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/example/exportable-grid-board) from AppSDK2 documentation that uses `portfolioitem/feature`.

There is a trick to make this work with AppSDK1 described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26048290/rallydatasource-update-is-not-working-for-portfolioitem-feature-works-for-users/26064744#26064744) 2 years back. Note that the trick will only allow you to bump up the corresponding [WS API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) version to 1.43, and not to the current 2.0.